# Obtaining class of returned object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to implement in Objective-C a proxy for an object in the following way:

```
- (NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    return [_proxifiedObject methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
}

- (void) forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    char returnType = invocation.methodSignature.methodReturnType[0];
    if(returnType == '@')
    {
        id anotherProxy = [[[MyProxy alloc] initWithInvocation:invocation] autorelease];
        [invocation setReturnValue:&anotherProxy];
    } else {
        invocation.target = _proxifiedObject;
        [invocation invoke];
    }
}
```

Another proxy should construct the object from this invocation. But while the object is under construction we should be able to collect and store invocations to it to have a chance to process them after the object is constructed. To achieve this I should implement 2 methods: methodSignatureForSelector: and forwardInvocation:. The second is quite easy but the first is what the question is all about.

We should know the class of the proxified object to be able to provide signature but the invocation which anotherProxy is initialized with does not provide information about the returned object's class. Is there a way to obtain the class of the object which will be returned by the method using Apple's Objective-C runtime?

**UPDATE**:

I understand that the actual class of the returned object may be different but there may be the only class with which the method is declared. If method is declared as

```
 - (SomeClass*) someMethod;
```

in the interface I expect SomeClass to be obtained.

**UPDATE**:

Finally I've solved my problem. The solution is not elegant but it 'just works'.
I've wrote this method:

```
static NSMutableDictionary* dictionarySelectorsToSignatures;

+ (NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForUnknownClassForSelector: (SEL) sel
{
    NSMethodSignature* candidate = [dictionarySelectorsToSignatures objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long) sel]];
    if(candidate == nil)
    {
        int classesCount = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
        Class* classes = malloc(sizeof(Class) * classesCount);
        objc_getClassList(classes, classesCount);
        for(int i = 0; i < classesCount; i++)
        {
            if(class_getClassMethod(classes[i], @selector(instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:)) != NULL)
            {
                NSMethodSignature* signature = [classes[i] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:sel];
                if(signature != nil)
                {
                    if(candidate != nil)
                    {
                        if(![candidate isEqual:signature])
                        {
                            return nil;
                        }
                    } else {
                        candidate = signature;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(candidate != nil)
        {
            [dictionarySelectorsToSignatures setObject:candidate 
                                                forKey:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long)  sel]];
        }
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

This method returns signature for selector if it is not ambiguous and nil in other case.
Its main con is the fact that it does not support class/list of classes modification in runtime thus it can be used only if all classes are registered and code does not modify classes (potentially risky to use it with KVO!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain the class of the object which will be returned by the method using Apple's Objective-C runtime?

No - if a method returns a class-type, you can't know the actual - concrete - type before it has returned. With the concrete class-type being unknown, you can't find out what return type any of it's method may have.

Comment: But is there a function (or smth else) that retrieves the declared type of the method?

Comment: @Vsevolod: In a case like `[[a f] g]`, you can get the signature for `f`, but not for `g` without invoking `f` first. That is because `f` and `g` are only message names and don't have a specific type. You only get method signatures from the combinations class & selector, protocol & selector or instance & selector.

Comment: Is this supposed to be fully generic or can you assume specific instances, use protocols on the caller side, ...?

Comment: That supposed to be fully generic.

Comment: OK. Let go from the problem. The problem I try to solve is to resend the message that proxy had received to the proxified object. I do not know the class of the proxified object since it does not exist yet. I can't get the class of it before it is created. Maybe there is any other way to archive my goal (resend message) that does not require method signature acquiring?

Comment: Does it have to have the same return types as the proxied object?

Comment: Yes, it does.
You can assume that we return only `id` and `void`.
If the return type is `void` we just postpone invoking of the method until proxified object is constructed. Actual return type for the caller is void.
If the return type is `id` we also postpone invoking of method but we return another proxy object to a caller.
If it brings us to the solution it is possible to make an assumption that the return type is always `void`.

Comment: @Vsevolod: Then you could just always use `@` as the return type - in the case of `void` return the value `NSNull` (the caller shouldn't care anyway).

Comment: What I needed was `NSMethodSignature` instance for `g` from your example above. Everything in my comments above refers that `g`. Yes, I know that I can use `@` _as the return type_. But I also needed the rest part of the signature. Now it is OK, I've found the solution that is satisfiable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to check if "instance" is an NSString

```
if ([instance isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]( {
  //do something
}
```

That good?

Comment: No. I need to obtain a Class not to check whether the object belongs to a specific class.

Comment: well if you have few possible classes, you can check which one is your variable an instance of, and you would know the class too

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual name of the class of the object:

e.g. for an object `foo`

```
NSLog(@"foo is an object of class %@", NSStringFromClass([foo class]));
```

Comment: That is not my case because I do not have an object itself. I have a method (actually not a method but an instance of NSInvocation) that returns an object.

Comment: Either way, you have an object - and you can use this to know what class it is. You don't have to use the NSLog statement, but the `NSStringFromClass()` function.